# SQL create flag based on earliest/latest date

Tags: sql

I have a data set with the following attributes:
- IDs are not unique and has multiple rows
- Each ID has a different date called 'Start Date'

I am trying to add a flag (Y/N) to determine which ID row to use, based on the earliest date.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *,
min(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS FirstEntryFlag,
From `table`
```

Could someone please give me guidance on how I would achieve this? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when start_date = min(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as FirstEntryFlag
from t;
```

If the start date has duplicates for an id and you want only one row flagged, use `row_number()`:

```
select (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by id order by Start_Date) 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as FirstEntryFlag
from t;
```

Finally, some databases support boolean types, so the `case` is not necessary.  Just the conditional expression can return a valid value.